# How to rearrange machine numbers on Juju?

Tags: juju

I have this output from `juju status`:

```
environment: manual
machines:
  "0":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.20.9
    dns-name: juju.local
    instance-id: 'manual:'
    series: trusty
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 mem=480M
    state-server-member-status: has-vote
  "1":
    agent-state: down
    agent-state-info: (started)
    agent-version: 1.20.9
    dns-name: mysql.local
    instance-id: manual:mysql.local
    series: trusty
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 mem=228M
  "2":
    agent-state: down
    agent-state-info: (started)
    agent-version: 1.20.9
    dns-name: zabbix.local
    instance-id: manual:zabbix.local
    series: trusty
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 mem=228M
  "5":
    agent-state: down
    agent-state-info: (started)
    agent-version: 1.20.9
    dns-name: b2b-server.local
    instance-id: manual:jenkins.local
    series: trusty
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=2 mem=7784M
services:
  juju-gui:
    charm: cs:trusty/juju-gui-10
    exposed: false
    units:
      juju-gui/0:
        agent-state: down
        agent-state-info: (started)
        agent-version: 1.20.9
        machine: "0"
        open-ports:
        - 80/tcp
        - 443/tcp
        public-address: juju.local
  mysql:
    charm: cs:trusty/mysql-7
    exposed: false
    relations:
      cluster:
      - mysql
      db:
      - zabbix
    units:
      mysql/0:
        agent-state: down
        agent-state-info: (started)
        agent-version: 1.20.9
        machine: "1"
        public-address: mysql.local
  zabbix:
    charm: cs:~ayrton/trusty/zabbix-3
    exposed: false
    relations:
      db:
      - mysql
units:
  zabbix/0:
    agent-state: down
    agent-state-info: (started)
    agent-version: 1.20.9
    machine: "2"
    open-ports:
    - 80/tcp
    - 10051/tcp
    public-address: jenkins.local
```

Sometimes I remove some machines and add another machines, and the machines appears like 0, 1, 2, 5...

How to rearrange the machines counter? Or how to manually change the machine identifier?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change the sequence number used for machine ids. It always starts at 0 and never goes back, even when you remove a machine and add another one. This is by design and is needed to maintain internal referential integrity of the DB.